# Assign static IP to ethernet card from OTG

Tags: android, ethernet

I would like to assign a static IP to an ethernet card, connected to the Android device via OTG cable.
It should be done programmatically, but I can't find any reference regarding ethernet cards in android.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: On a stock, non-rooted Android device, there is unlikely to be any support for a USB ethernet adapter, so I expect you will have to implement the entire network stack in userspace within your application, coding against the Android USB host APIs.  That's going to be a huge project - but if you get it done, setting a static IP will be a fairly trivial task.

Answer (score 3):

If its a rooted device you can try with this

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "netcfg eth0 192.168.0.123"});
process.waitFor();
```

And also you can use `ifconfig` instead of `netcfg`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the device should not be rooted;

Comment: Do your device have ethernet port ??

Comment: No, just a mini-usb port where I connect an external ethernet card

Comment: That need some specific drivers installed on device.

Comment: I tried this solution for rooted device, but its not working. Can someone point me how to do it in rooted device

Comment: @CharanPai can you help me out here?

Comment: I am using a rooted device, running the suggested command. Command successfully running without any error, but IP is not changed in the device.