# Set static ip to ethernet in android

Tags: android, network-programming, ethernet

I have ethernet connected to my android board.
I want to manually set IP from code. I was able to set IP address for WIFI.
I have looked into following links for ethernet

[Assign static IP to ethernet card from OTG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397803/assign-static-ip-to-ethernet-card-from-otg) 
So far I have not found how to set static IP to ethernet via android code.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this without running `su -c` commands on the phone?

Comment: No, I did not find any solution.

Comment: how you set ip in WIFI?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to create /data/misc/ethernet/ipconfig.txt file to configure static IP address.
As you successfully configured static IP address for WiFi already,
I think /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt was also created and it will be valid for Ethernet config, too.
Please refer to following links for file path and data format.
[EthernetConfigStore.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/ethernet/+/master/java/com/android/server/ethernet/EthernetConfigStore.java)
[IpConfigStore.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/net/IpConfigStore.java)

Comment: together with this tool this seems to be a great answer https://github.com/jhswartz/ipconfigstore

Comment: There is a much simpler way of doing this by GUI, i just don't remember the steps, and i need this for a client... damm friday XD

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set Ip to Ethernet connection as follows.
I was using Allwinner A31s android board.

```
String command1 = "su -c ifconfig eth0 "
                        + terminalIpAddressString+" netmask "
                        + subnetMaskAddressString
                        +" up";
                String command2 = "route add default gw "
                        + gatewayAddressString+" dev eth0";



                String command3 = "mount -o remount,rw /system";
                String command4 = "echo \"su -c ifconfig eth0 "
                        +terminalIpAddressString+" netmask "
                        +subnetMaskAddressString+" up;" +
                        "route add default gw "
                        +gatewayAddressString
                        +" dev eth0\" > /system/bin/preinstall.sh";

                String command5 = "busybox sed -i 's/su -c ifconfig eth0 "
                        +terminalIpAddressString
                        +" netmask "+subnetMaskAddressString+" up;"
                        +"route add default gw 172.19.10.2 dev eth0"
                        + "/su -c ifconfig eth0 "+terminalIpAddressString
                        +" netmask "+subnetMaskAddressString+" up;"
                        +"route add default gw "+gatewayAddressString
                        +" dev eth0/g' /system/bin/preinstall.sh";
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: This is a poor answer, in that the OP sought to do this via Android code, not commands to the underlying operating system.